# Losing values with array_merge

Tags: php, arrays, array-merge

I have an array:

```
{
  "zone1":{
    "foo1":"bar1",
    "foo2":"bar2",
    "foo3":"bar3",
    "foo4":"bar4"
  },
  "zone2":{
    "newfoo1":"newbar1",
    "newfoo2":"newbar2",
    "newfoo3":"newbar3",
    "newfoo4":"newbar4"
  },
  "zone3":{
    "morefoo1":"morebar1",
    "morefoo2":"morebar2",
    "morefoo3":"morebar3",
    "morefoo4":"morebar4"
  }
}
```

And I want to merge a second array with updated values:

```
{
  "zone1":{
    "foo1":"updatedbar1"
  },
  "zone3":{
    "morefoo2":"updatedbar2",
    "morefoo4":"updatedbar4"
  }
}
```

I have tried many things, what Im using now is this php code:

```
$array3 = array_merge($array1, $array2);
```

But this code give me this:

```
{
  "zone1":{
    "foo1":"updatedbar1"
  },
  "zone2":{
    "newfoo1":"newbar1",
    "newfoo2":"newbar2",
    "newfoo3":"newbar3",
    "newfoo4":"newbar4"
  },
  "zone3":{
    "morefoo2":"updatedbar2",
    "morefoo4":"updatedbar4"
  }
}
```

What I want is just update the first array with the values on the second array, without losing any data.
Arrays are json, they are from json files, but the language is PHP.

Comment: What programming language?

Comment: The call to `array_merge` is clearly PHP, but your arrays are shown here as JSON.  Please clarify.

Comment: Yes, my arrays are from json files using both json_decode and json_encode. My language is PHP.

Comment: if you showed the php arrays, it would be more helpful than the json ones

Comment: Or just add `(array)` before each array variable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`array_replace_recursive()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-replace-recursive.php):

```
$array3 = array_replace_recursive($array1, $array2);
```

It creates the following array with your data:

```
Array
(
    [zone1] => Array
        (
            [foo1] => updatedbar1
            [foo2] => bar2
            [foo3] => bar3
            [foo4] => bar4
        )

    [zone2] => Array
        (
            [newfoo1] => newbar1
            [newfoo2] => newbar2
            [newfoo3] => newbar3
            [newfoo4] => newbar4
        )

    [zone3] => Array
        (
            [morefoo1] => morebar1
            [morefoo2] => updatedbar2
            [morefoo3] => morebar3
            [morefoo4] => updatedbar4
        )

)
```

See it on [ideone](http://ideone.com/NlOFOE).

Answer (score 0):

array_merge() only merges the top-level array, and doesn't take account of arrays-within-arrays. Therefor, duplicate values will be overwritten by the latter array.

You can solve this using `array_merge_recursive()`:

```
$ar1 = array("color" => array("favorite" => "red"), 5);
$ar2 = array(10, "color" => array("favorite" => "green", "blue"));
$result = array_merge_recursive($ar1, $ar2);
```

More info can be found on the [php.net page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge-recursive.php)

-- 
**EDIT**

The first comment on the page mentioned above explains how to merge two arrays while using the second one to update the first one:

```
<?php
/**
* array_merge_recursive does indeed merge arrays, but it converts values with duplicate
* keys to arrays rather than overwriting the value in the first array with the duplicate
* value in the second array, as array_merge does. I.e., with array_merge_recursive,
* this happens (documented behavior):
*
* array_merge_recursive(array('key' => 'org value'), array('key' => 'new value'));
*     => array('key' => array('org value', 'new value'));
*
* array_merge_recursive_distinct does not change the datatypes of the values in the     arrays.
* Matching keys' values in the second array overwrite those in the first array, as is     the
* case with array_merge, i.e.:
*
* array_merge_recursive_distinct(array('key' => 'org value'), array('key' => 'new value'));
*     => array('key' => array('new value'));
*
* Parameters are passed by reference, though only for performance reasons. They're     not
* altered by this function.
*
* @param array $array1
* @param array $array2
* @return array
* @author Daniel <daniel (at) danielsmedegaardbuus (dot) dk>
* @author Gabriel Sobrinho <gabriel (dot) sobrinho (at) gmail (dot) com>
*/
function array_merge_recursive_distinct ( array &$array1, array &$array2 )
{
  $merged = $array1;

  foreach ( $array2 as $key => &$value )
  {
    if ( is_array ( $value ) && isset ( $merged [$key] ) && is_array ( $merged [$key] ) )
    {
      $merged [$key] = array_merge_recursive_distinct ( $merged [$key], $value );
    }
    else
    {
  $merged [$key] = $value;
    }
  }

  return $merged;
}
?>
```

Comment: it is recursive, I tryed it and the values that are in both arrays will not be overwritten, will be one each other, like this: "newfoo1":["newbar1","updatedbar1"]

Comment: Seems that is working with 'array_replace_recursive', tomorrow I will do more testing and if it fails I will try your edit, thanks.